# equivalent Hertzian contact pair for arbitrarily shaped bodies in 2D

Tags: solid-mechanics, tribology

I am a bit new to this field here.  I am trying to determine the contact stress between two arbitrarily shaped bodies that are indenting into each other (see attached image).  I would like to solve for the contact stress using an equivalent sphere/plane pair and Hertzian contact.  Is there a way to determine this (even approximately) in 2D?  Are the jagged surfaces allowable?  Any pointers would help.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: could you update the question and provide in it the shapes of the bodies separately? from your current shape its not easy to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Sharp corners will cause the local contact stresses to be much higher than for the entire contact surface, skewing your estimate of the average load due to contact if you use a simplified spherical/cylindrical model.

To get better estimates, you'll have to do numerical simulations with accurate geometries and techniques such as finite elements with mortar contact algorithms.